# Firebase Keyed JSON to convert into items for Polymer iron-list; or access nested JSON?

Tags: json, polymerfire, firebase-polymer

I've tried lots of options to get **Firebase** Key-indexed **JSON** to display db text and images (from storage) into *divs* and *template* by using *getElementById* and it works for only setting the elements of the *last* db record received for the template. 
But I'm trying a ***Polymer iron-list***... and just can't get it.

I can't use *iron-ajax* since the firebase database url gives *CORS header errors*.
I've tried creating a Polymer property Array that returns a function, but that works only for a hardcoded array that I manually removed to key from to test.

I've looked at Firebase *Document* and Firebase *Collection*, which refer to Firebase *Query*... but I can't figure out how to change oldData for newData in an observer function, and data's not going to change much, not yet anyway. And trying to set *iron-list items* = a *Polymer property Array* with a *computed* function option doesn't even get to invoke that part of the property code for some reason.

1. How should **Firebase** Key-indexed **JSON** content be put ***automatically*** into a *dom-repeat Tempate* and into an *Iron-list* please?

It seems to go against grain to manipulate and iterate through the Object converted to Array in a for-loop like some answers suggest.
But if the only option i would, what would be needed is to convert
eg:

{"-KcKDbyGIwd.." :{ UserId : "Tri0IP..MruqLs1",desc : "king's horses"}, ..., {} }, to:

{ UserId : "Tri0IP..MruqLs1", desc : "king's horses"}, ..., {}

2. How do I strip the key off each record please?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help...

Answer (score 0):

This should work!

```
  <iron-list items="[[data]]" as="item">
    <template>
      <div>
        Name: [[item.name]]
      </div>
    </template>
  </iron-list>
```

Comment: Hi Joel, thanks for replying... your approach works only from the Properties or from the ready function and the *data* in a HARD-CODED array WITHOUT the firebase push keys, the *data* appears... BUT can't get to see anything *automatically* ... the way *iron-list* or *dom-repeat template* work.    ...BTW using *snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot)...* gives just the child without the push key.